# Roles in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, roles

Following users are created in mongodb
first user created with name "user" having read write role for "project" database
use project

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "user",
      pwd: "user123",
      roles: [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "project" },
         { role: "readAnyDatabase", db:"admin" }
      ]
    }
)
```

second user created with name "stud" having read write role for "student" database
use student

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "stud",
      pwd: "stud123",
      roles: [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "stud" },
         { role: "readAnyDatabase", db:"admin" }
      ]
    }
)
```

When I connected to database having name project using "user" I am getting project as well as student database. Also to able to add collection in student database. I havent give any permission to "user" to access student database. Still it is possible to access student database. How to avoid it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this is a community for **software developers**. Your question, however, requires the expertise of a **database administrator**. I therefore voted to migrate this question to our sister-site https://dba.stackexchange.com. In the future, please try to always pick the stackexchange which is most appropriate for your question.

Comment: Hopefully this will migrate to where it belongs soon, but in the meantime, I can't replicate your problem. When I run the commands you gave, `user` can read database `student` because `user` has the `readAnyDatabase` role. `user` cannot write to database `student`.